# How to select the audio output device in a web app (ionic)?

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I have a webrtc based voicecall in my ionic based app. On android the sound comes out of the speaker. how can I select the output sink?
I have found the reference to the function setSinkId of the HTMLMediaElement, but this seems not to be supported on android. 
Does anyone have a clue?